# How to install NDK in Fedora?

Tags: linux, android-ndk, installation, fedora, configure

I want to install and configure **NDK** in my System which is having **Linux** operating system. I have study this link about **NDK**.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html, from which i have got basic knowledge about **NDK** but not getting any specific answer about how to **install**, **configure** and use **NDK**, I am new to **NDK** so i am confused how could i do next things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to install or configure: you just have to download it, and unzip it to a some location on your disk. If you want to be able to use its tools such as `ndk-build` easily from everywhere, you just have to add this folder to your PATH.

As for how to use it, even though there is no detailed documentation on developer.android.com, there is a `documentation.html` file in the NDK directory, which contains much more information. You can also explore the sample projects contained in the NDK folder, starting with `hello-jni` .

Comment: Thanks mbrenon for giving me useful details, but my getting installation process of it on Windows,Mac but not on Linux so please clear this or send me any Link.